# Needed to open infowindow when mouseover polygon in Google maps

Tags: javascript, google-maps, events, listener, infowindow

I would like to have the same functionality on google maps with the info window on mouse hover over a postal code as they have it on the site in the link below:
https://www.bloomberg.com/graphics/property-prices/london/?utm_content=graphics&utm_campaign=socialflow-organic&utm_source=twitter&utm_medium=social&cmpid%3D=socialflow-twitter-graphics

The given site uses openstreetmaps, while I'm using google maps.
The code I've created by now is in "mouseover" listener and within it I'm using "mousemove" listener and and anchor. So first I'm styling the polygons which are created on top off a google maps layer with geojson data after i create an info window and open it on the event . 
    infoWindow: new google.maps.InfoWindow({ content: "" })

```
sectorLayer.addListener('mouseover', function(e) {
    sectorLayer.overrideStyle(e.feature, {
        strokeColor: '#fff',
        ...
    });
    infoWindow.setContent('Test content');
    anchor.set("position", e.latLng);
    google.maps.event.addListenerOnce(map, 'mousemove', function(){
          infoWindow.close();
    });
```

This code is not doing the desired effects as on the webpage in the link above.

Comment: So are you saying that nothing in your code is working as expected at all? Tell me what is working based on the above code and the errors you are getting

Comment: The above code is working but not in the way I would intend it to be. I would like some idea as to how to achieve the effect as in the link, but on google maps. So when you hover over a polygon on map layer you would have a info window open and would display information about that polygon, and the infowindow should follow the cursor as it moves on the page.